# Printing XAML - Missing Font issue

Tags: xaml, printing, fonts, xps, custom-font

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xps printing from windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123507/xps-printing-from-windows-service)

I have a custom .TTF font that is referenced in a XAML document.

ex:

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="custom font name">render me</TextBlock>
```

1. if I view the xaml document in IE the font renders just fine
2. If I print the xaml to an .xps file, the font will render just fine when I view the .xps document in IE
3. if I try to print the xaml document to a regular printer, the font is not rendered, and a default face is used instead.
4. if I try to print the .xps document to a regular printer the font is not rendered, and a default face is used instead

I have tried embedding the font as a resource, I have tried referencing the font file directly both in the XAML and in the code-behind of the xaml.

I can take a plain html file, reference the font and print it to the regular printer, and it renders just fine.

how can I get this custom font to print correctly in this XAML document?

Comment: Does the .xps document render correctly on a machine where the font is not installed?

Comment: yes. i blew out the font, and it still renders correctly in the xps file...however when I print the xps it still fails to render the font

Comment: @ERolnicki: Bugger.  I am dealing with the same thing right now.  If you have any movement on this, please let me know.  If I find anything, I'll add an answer.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123507/xps-printing-from-windows-service it might be a spooling issue.  I'm trying that next.

Comment: I'd answer, but spooling fixed it.  Not exactly the best solution, but it definitely has something to do with the problem.